# How to Select a column based on string

Tags: matlab

So I have a Cell say its 5x5

```
  1 2 3 4 5
1 A B C D E
2 X X X X X
3 X X X X X
4 X X X X X
5 X X X X X
```

In Matlab how do I select a column based on the string in the first row. Say I want all the values in the C column but I dont have the index of C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mycell(:,strcmp(mycell(1,:),'C'))
```